# ffmpeg: Is there a way to decode a video frame, given the previous frame, motion vectors, and a residual image?

Tags: python, c, ffmpeg, mpeg-4, video-compression

Assume we are given the following numpy arrays: the BGR video frame for timestep t-1, the motion vectors for timestep t, and the residual image for timestep t. Also, assume the video frame, motion vectors, and residual iamge, come from a video which was compressed using mpeg-4.

Using these inputs, *how would we use ffmpeg to decode the BGR video frame for timestep t*?

I tried manually reconstructing the t frame by: (1) creating a reference frame, which is just a copy of the t-1 frame; (2) performing motion compensation by copying 16x16 pixel blocks from the t-1 frame to the reference frame, based on the motion vectors; (3) adding the residual image to the motion-compensated reference frame.

However, the resulting predicted t frame doesn't exactly match the actual t frame, so I feel that this might not be the right way to do it.

Comment: This sounds like a really interesting topic, but I'm not sure that Stack Overflow is the right place to ask this question.

Comment: MPEG-4 video decoding performs IDCT(Inverse discrete cosine transform) process. ISO MPEG-4 Standard define IDCT with floating point number, so each Decoder implementation may output slightly different frame by computation error.